# Save ng-repeat data in Array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat

In my MongoDB I have attributes collection, I would like to add a new field "odoo_name" to each attribute and save it.

For example I have 100 attributes and each attribute will have an odoo_name field to update the old database.

**Problem :** my console.log(odoo_name) shows **undefined**, it's not seeing the name filled into the input field.

I changed ng-submit function to saveOdooNames(vm.localAttributes) I am getting all data but when I try to access the ng-model still get **undefined** console.log (inputs.odoo_name)

```
<form ng-submit="saveOdooNames(i)">
      <button>Save</button>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul class="grid">
          <li data-ng-repeat="i in vm.localAttributes">
            <label>
              <div class="attribute-msl-link-label-wrap">
                <div class="attribute-msl-link-label">
                  <span class="attribute-icon">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i>
                  </span>
                  <span class="attribute-number">{{ i.number_id }}</span>
                  <span class="attribute-title" title="{{i.project.name}}">{{ i.name }}</span>
                  <input ng-model="i.odoo_name" type="text" class="form-control"/>
                  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="del-attr" data-id="{{ i._id}}" data-parent="0">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </form>
```

This is my controller :

```
$scope.saveOdooNames = function (o) {
  var inputs = [];
   inputs.push(o);     
  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    format: 'json',
    url: '/api/odoonames',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    data: { _id : inputs._id,
            odoo_name : inputs.odoo_name }

  }).then(function (success) {
    console.log('Success ' + JSON.stringify(success));
  }, function (error) {
    console.error("Error " + JSON.stringify(error));
  });    
};
```

PS : It works if I save fields one by one, but I need to bulk save these fields.

**EDIT :**

I updated `ng-submit="saveOdooNames(i)"` to `ng-submit=vm.localAttributes)"`

**End Edit**

The save button should store all input data in an **Array** (inputs)

Comment: you want to save all attributes then instead of passing 'i' to function pass (vm.localAttributes) you will get all attributes

Comment: @KumailHussain yes I tried it but when I want to extract name and ids it shows undefined

Comment: console the whole data and see what you get i.e $scope.saveOdooNames = function (o) { cosnole.log(o);.....

Comment: do your html shows the whole data?

Comment: @KumailHussain yes my html shows all data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, i was missing that i was getting an array of objects and i was trying to save the array into the inputs array. After I called it without specifying the index which was normal to have "undefined" 
here is what I needed :

**SOLUTION 1 :**

```
 $scope.saveOdooNames = function(o) {                    
            var data = [];
            for (var i = 0; i<o.length; i++) {                
                data.push({_id: o[i]._id,odoo_name: o[i].odoo_name});                
            }
            console.log(data);
            // $http post code 
          };
```

But the code above, returns all odoo_name fields even not "touched" or changed so I used the second solution.

**SOLUTION 2 :**

I used underscore filter and without passing "o" in the function calling directly my model

```
$scope.saveOdooNames = function () {          

            var o = _.filter(vm.localAttributes, function (x) {
              return x.odoo_name;
            });
            var data = [];
            for (var i = 0; i<o.length; i++) {                
                data.push({_id: o[i]._id,odoo_name: o[i].odoo_name});                
            }
            console.log(data);
            // $http post code
}
```

Both solutions work just this one with filter, I could use angular filters for the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You should just link the save function to the button, instead of using i as param which is undefined because the ng-repeat is nested lower inside the div, use vm.localAttributes and you'll have your data in your function.

```
<form>
    <button ng-click="saveOdooNames(vm.localAttributes)">Save</button>
....
```

Comment: but when I get the data still cannot extract ids and names sending "null" to nodejs

Comment: Please link a plunkr of your problem, because that code is working fine on my part.

Comment: when i try console.log(inputs._id, inputs.odoo_name) it shows undefined and iam sending null to the server (nodejs)

Comment: Of course it's undefined, it's only defined for each children inside the inputs array

Comment: undefined because" o" is an array and iam trying to call for _id or odoo_name without defining the its index thank you for passing by

Answer (score 1):

$http method should be returned where used, it's a promise. Also, you getting `o` and then pushing it into an array, then doing some kind of object assignment WITHOUT referencing the index of the array. Once you add the return statement, you still might have to refactor the data you're assigning in the data params. Hope this helps and gets you going in the right direction.

```js
function processNamesRequest(inputs) {
  return $http({
    method: 'POST',
    format: 'json',
    url: '/api/odoonames',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    data: {
      _id: inputs._id,
      odoo_name: inputs.odoo_name
    }

  }).then(function(success) {
    console.log('Success ' + JSON.stringify(success));
  }, function(error) {
    console.error("Error " + JSON.stringify(error));
  });
}
$scope.saveOdooNames = function(o) {
  //if you dont need an array here 
  //i would just send `o` as is in the request
  var inputs = [];
  inputs.push(o);
  return processNamesRequest(inputs)
};

/*Refactored: I'd also consider putting all http requests inside of a factory or a service.*/

function processNamesRequest(input) {
  return $http({
      method: 'POST',
      format: 'json',
      url: '/api/odoonames',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      data: {
        _id: input._id,
        odoo_name: input.odoo_name
      }

    })
    .then(function(success) {
      console.log('Success ' + JSON.stringify(success));
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Error " + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
}
$scope.saveOdooNames = function(o) {
  return processNamesRequest(o)
};
```

Comment: thank you for your time, yes you are right its about the index, actually i solved the issue what i was missing is that " o" is an array and iam trying to save it into array instead of specifying its index, i was just blind to not see this earlier